# Using Plastic SCM Cloud and the Plastic SCM Proxy server

Tags: plasticscm

Is it possible to use the Plastic SCM Proxy when using the Plastic SCM Cloud Edition?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Plastic SCM Cloud Edition is not supporting the "Proxy" server check the features matrix [here](https://www.plasticscm.com/pricing.html). You'll need an Enterprise Edition in order to use the Proxy Server.

That being said, can I ask you why do you need a Proxy server? You can use your local one in order to pull info from your central Plastic SCM server? It's going to be faster and you can work distributed, then once you finish your work you can push back your changes.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding what the feature set is in regards to cloud.  We want to reduce bandwidth between our office and the cloud service, and from what I had read the Proxy server is the way to do that, but if you're suggesting we can do that with a local server in the office while using the cloud service then could you point me to the documentation for that please?